# Different results of DESeq2 in different ways of comparison

Tags: deseq2

I have different treatments (infected and control ones). When using DESeq2, I have different results in two ways of comparison.
first way:

factor: treatment, factor level1: Moribund Infected, factor level2: 5week Infected, factor level3: Moribund Control, factor level4: 5week Control.
I have 6 result files (comparisons among factor levels)

second way: (I compared just 2 groups to each other)

```
factor: treatment, factor level1: Moribund Infected, factor level2: 5week Infected.
factor: treatment, factor level1: Moribund Infected, factor level2: Moribund Control.
factor: treatment, factor level1: Moribund Infected, factor level2:the  5week Control.
factor: treatment, factor level1: 5week Infected, factor level2: Moribund Control.
factor: treatment, factor level1: 5week Infected, factor level2: 5week Control.
factor: treatment, factor level 1: Moribund Control, factor level2: 5week Control.
```

Finally, the results were different in these two ways of comparison. I have more significantly expressed genes in most comparisons of first way and even I have few comparisons in the second way that have more significantly expressed genes.

Why and which way is trustable?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please show the specific design formulas you used to describe the statistical models in the DESeq2 commands. Showing the full factor table would be helpful as well (e.g. `colData` in the DESeq2 commands).

Comment: Cross-posted:https://support.bioconductor.org/p/9144330/